# Woocommerce: Dynamically change attributes / parameters of a WC Render-Block

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I use the Woocommerce “Handpicked products” Block in Wordpress Gutenberg to create a showcase of 3 products on my Frontpage. I saw that Woocommerce does not use Shortcodes for that, but that the page itself includes a paragraph which looks like this:

```
<!-- wp:woocommerce/handpicked-products {"contentVisibility":{"image":true,"title":true,"price":false,"rating":false,"button":false},"orderby":"menu_order","products":[181,225,179]} /-->"
```

I want to dynamically change the products (randomly shuffle) upon page load. Unfortunately, in the whole PHP-classes HandpickedProducts, AbstractProductGrid, AbstractDynamicBlock etc I do not see a Hook to change the Render parameter dynamically...

So what I found as possible solution is: To directly replace the product attribute in the Wordpress Post itself, therefore I implemented this hook:

```
function my_the_post_action(&$pobj) {
    $pobj->post_content = str_replace('[181,225,179]', '[225, 220, 222]', $pobj->post_content );
}
add_action('the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );
```

It is actually replaced in the wp:woocommerce/handpicked-products paragraph, but doesnt take effect. Why does Woocommerce not consider the new Product IDs as parameters to his rendered block?

Thanks!!

Comment: The loop of products i guess happens on earlier stage of loading than the_post action. Try hooking into set_block_query_args maybe ?

Comment: I am not fan of blocks so i dont know much about the hooks they have but check this maybe - build_query_vars_from_query_block https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/build_query_vars_from_query_block/

Comment: @MartinMirchev Thanks for the idea - I came up with another idea instead, which I feel is cleaner anyhow instead of modifying the original Page/Post content itself... Originally I didnt know about the "do_blocks()" function, that's why I originally thought to modify page content. But this way it's better I feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of modifying the "Blocks" entered via Pageeditor upon Pageload within the Frontpage - I came up with a better and cleaner option IMHO - by simply rendering such a Block within a customer Shortcode.

The following code consists of first the part where I randomly pick 3 products from the Database which have the Product-Tag "Featured" set so that the user can decide himself which products are open for selection ... and then I create my "Handpicked Products" block and render it:

```
add_shortcode('my_featured_prods', function($atts, $content = null)
{
    // Get list of all Woocommerce products by Tag
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'featured'
            )
        )
    );

    $products = new WP_Query($args);
    $ids = [$fix];
    foreach($products->posts as $p)
        $ids[] = $p->ID;

    // Shuffle array:
    shuffle($ids);

    // Output Hand Picked Products Widget with my settings ...
    $args = (object) [
        'editMode' => 0,
        'contentVisibility' => (object) [
            'image' => 1,
            'title' => 1,
            'price' => 0,
            'rating' => 0,
            'button' => 0,
        ],
        'orderby' => 'random',
        'products' => $ids,
        'alignButtons' => 1,
    ];
    $args = sprintf(
        '<!-- wp:woocommerce/handpicked-products %s /-->',
        json_encode( $args )
    );

    return do_blocks($args);
});
```